# Handling Multiple wait operation before entering into critical section in operating system?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

I am stuck while solving a counting semaphore problem in Operating system subject.

```
S is a semaphore initialized to 5.

count = 0 (shared variable) 

Assume that the increment operation in line #7 is not atomic.
```

**Now,**

```
1.  int counter = 0;
2.  Semaphore S = init(5);
3.  void parop(void)
4.  {
5.         wait(S);
6.         wait(S);
7.         counter++;
8.         signal(S);
9.         signal(S);
10.  }
```

***If five threads execute the function parop concurrently, which of the following program behavior(s) is/are possible?***

**A.**  The value of counter is 5 after all the threads successfully complete the execution of parop

**B.**  The value of counter is 1 after all the threads successfully complete the execution of parop

**C.** The value of counter is 0 after all the threads successfully complete the execution of parop

**D.** There is a deadlock involving all the threads

what i have understand till now is answer is **A and D**,because what if all process are executed one by one say(T1->T2->T3->T4->T5) and final value saved will be 5(**so A is one of correct options**)
Now, **why D**,because what if all process execute line 5 before 6 and will get blocked.

*Now, please can any one help me to understand why **B** is another correct answer.* ?

Thanks in advance,

Hope to here from you soon

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine `thread 1` gets to line 7 before any other thread, and line 7 is implemented as three instructions:

```
7_1:  load counter, %r0
7_2:  add  $1, %r0
7_3:  store %r0, counter
```

For some reason (eg. interrupt, preempted), `thread 1` stops at instruction `7_2`; so it has loaded the value 0 into register `%r0`.

Next, `thread's 2..5` all run through this sequence, leaving counter at say `4`.

`Thread 1` is rescheduled, increments `%r0` to the value `1` and stores it into `counter`.

Comment: thanks for your help.Can you please explain why there are 2 wait() before critical section.

Comment: Its just a needless detail to make the problem harder to understand.   I could write a function: `Wait2(Semaphore *S) { Wait(*S); Wait(*S); }` and `Sig2(Semaphore *S) { Signal(*S); Signal(*S); }` then rewrite the original as `Wait2(&Semaphore); counter++; Signal2(&Semaphore);` without changing the critical semantic:  `only two threads can execute line 7 at a time`.  But even that isn't helpful; if all 5 threads simultaneously executed line 7, your result could be any number between `1 and 5`.